# Use selectors module for sockets in Python

Tags: python, sockets

Hello I'm new to python and the other day I was reading a website which talks about how to use MultiServer with the `selectors` module instead of using the `threading` module.

My question is that I don't understand how this works?
Could someone explain to me how it works?

thank you.

Comment: What is MultiServer?  Google doesn't come up with anything obvious for it.

Comment: I want to say multiSocketServer